# Is actual fact redundant?

Tags: redundancy

I know that a **fact** is a **fact** and if words are used carefully there’s no real need to remind people that your fact is **actual**.

Now, that a lot of famous English [writers](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22actual%20fact%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1983,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) use this construction might be understandable, but that the [OED Additions](http://books.google.ro/books?id=gUGcAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&dq=%22actual+fact%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hD0EVP6gAsLuaMLhgcAN&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22actual%20fact%22&f=false) uses this redundancy to define some terms is beyond my comprehension unless it is an accepted redundancy.

Comment: I'm sure that the OED link you provided me with will throw a message *You have reached the page that is unavailable for viewing...* to many as it did to me. :(

Comment: On the same page you have linked (OED Additions) there should be a defn. #5 of _actual_ defined as an intensifier. Pretty much redundant but very commonly used. I think there might be more to it than that (actual fact vs natural fact - I'm not sure those are even the right 'terms') but I don't have the time at the moment.

Comment: Take a close look at the origin of the word "actual" given in dictionaries. It came into Middle English from Old French where it meant "acting, practical". This meaning is pretty much lost in English, but lost meanings are routinely preserved in set phrases. If this is the case, then "actual fact" does not mean "factual fact", it means "acting fact". It is the fact which controls the situation as opposed to a sea of dubious or irrelevant facts.

Comment: Incidentally, the word "actual" entered Russian too as "актуальный" (aktualniy). Ozhegov's dictionary (1986 edition) gives: "1) Very important for the present. 'An actual topic.' 2) Existing, manifesting itself in reality." It presumably came into Russian from French in the 18th or 19th century. Some of these meanings may still be in French from which they would influence educated English writers who until recently often read French.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, *actual fact* would be redundant.  However, there may be limited situations where its use might be justified for emphasis or contrast.  Example:

> Instead of believing the facts on the Internet about vaccination, you should consult medical journals for the actual facts.

"Facts on the Internet" is being used sarcastically there to mean "myths".

Answer (score 1):

The main definition of the word "actual" is "real" or "up-to-date" -- See "actualize" to understand this meaning better. So an "actual fact" is a real, up-to-date fact. Therefore no redundancy. Compare with this example: "No. He is my step-father. My actual father lives in France."